# How to connect TableCell control with underlying row model in javafx?

Tags: javafx, tableview, spinner, fxml

I am using a TableView which is populated by my model.

I want to use a spinner control in one column.

I am able to create the spinner in the cells in the desired column,
but I am struggling to bind the spinners value to the models property.

This is the fxml

```
<ScrollPane>
   <content>
      <TableView prefHeight="525.0" prefWidth="814.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="state"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Side">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="side"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Source">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="sourceContract"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Reference">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="referenceContract"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Destination">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="destinationContract"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Margin" editable="true">
            <cellFactory><SpinnerTableCellFactory /></cellFactory>
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="margin"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Bot">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="bot"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Price">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="price"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Volume">
            <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="volume"/></cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
        </columns>
        <items>
          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <GridRowModel state="false" side="BID" sourceContract="s01" referenceContract="" destinationContract="d01" margin="0" bot="MinMax" price="15.125" volume="0" />
            <GridRowModel state="false" side="ASK" sourceContract="s02" referenceContract="" destinationContract="d02" margin="0" bot="MinMax" price="15.125" volume="0" />
          </FXCollections>
        </items>
      </TableView>
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

And this is the `SpinnerTableCellFactory`

```
public class SpinnerTableCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, Double>, TableCell<S, Double>> {

  @Override
  public TableCell<S, Double> call(TableColumn<S, Double> param) {

    return new TableCell<S, Double>() {

      Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<>(0d, 1d, 0d, 0.025d);

      protected void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
          setText(null);
          setGraphic(null);
        } else {
          if (isEditing()) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
          } else {
            spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(getItem());
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(spinner);
          }
        }
      };
    };
  }
}
```

When the fxml is loaded the `updateItem` method is called with the default values from the fxml for the `margin` property. I can see and use the spinner in the cells. But how do I pass any new spinner value back to the margin property in the GridRowModel object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just register a listener with the spinner's `valueProperty()`:

```
public class SpinnerTableCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, Double>, TableCell<S, Double>> {

  @Override
  public TableCell<S, Double> call(TableColumn<S, Double> param) {

    return new TableCell<S, Double>() {

      Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<>(0d, 1d, 0d, 0.025d);

      {
          spinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
              ObservableValue<Double> value = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
              if (value instanceof WritableValue) {
                  ((WritableValue<Double>)value).setValue(newValue); 
              }
          });
      }

      protected void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
          setText(null);
          setGraphic(null);
        } else {
          if (isEditing()) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
          } else {
            spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(getItem());
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(spinner);
          }
        }
      };
    };
  }
}
```

I'm assuming here that your model class `GridRowModel` follows the [JavaFX properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107).

If you don't use JavaFX Properties, or want to avoid the cast, you can give the cell factory a `BiConsumer<GridRowModel, Double>` to process updates:

```
public class SpinnerTableCellFactory<S, T> implements Callback<TableColumn<S, Double>, TableCell<S, Double>> {

  private BiConsumer<S, Double> updater = null ;

  public void setUpdater(BiConsumer<S, Double> updater) {
      this.updater = updater ;
  }

  @Override
  public TableCell<S, Double> call(TableColumn<S, Double> param) {

    return new TableCell<S, Double>() {

      Spinner<Double> spinner = new Spinner<>(0d, 1d, 0d, 0.025d);

      {
          spinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
              if (updater != null) {
                  updater.accept(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()), newValue);
              }
          });
      }

      protected void updateItem(Double item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
          setText(null);
          setGraphic(null);
        } else {
          if (isEditing()) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
          } else {
            spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(getItem());
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(spinner);
          }
        }
      };
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can add a `fx:id` to your factory:

```
<cellFactory><SpinnerTableCellFactory fx:id="marginCellFactory" /></cellFactory>
```

and in your controller do:

```
@FXML
private SpinnerTableCellFactory<GridRowModel, Double> marginCellFactory ;

public void initialize() {
    marginCellFactory.setUpdater(GridRowModel::setMargin);
}
```